# Does mixing violate conservation of energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation

If two fluids in an isolated system mix, the entropy of the system increases.  The volume and the number of particles in the system, however, are constant.  Thus $$dU=TdS+PdV-\mu dN=TdS>0$$ which violates conservation of energy.  What is wrong with this?

Comment: If you are mixing two equal molecular species at the same temperature and pressure, then the mixing entropy is indeed zero. If you are not, then characterizing the system with just one N makes no sense, neither before nor after the mixing.

Comment: OK, so then how would the equation $TdS-\mu_A dN_A-\mu_B dN_B=0$ balance?

Comment: By the two PdV terms (that you have just lost for no good reason) changing. When you dilute one molecular species in another, the least you are doing is to change the effective volume and the pressure for both of them.